# Sticky Rice Culture (Korea) vs. Fluffy Rice Culture (West)

Tags: vocabulary

In a book I am reading, there is a reference to Korea as being '자 진밥 문화' (찹 쌀) and the U.S. '메진밥 문화'.  The analogy seems to fit, but I have never heard of these phrases.  Would the average Korean know what I was trying to say?  If not, what is a better way to put it?

Comment: No. Honestly speaking, I’ve _just_ seen the words “차지다” and “메지다” for the first time ever. I had to look up the dictionary….

Answer (score 1):

I understand what they mean but never heard anyone using the phrases -- '자 진밥 문화' (찹 쌀) and the U.S. '메진밥 문화'. I would use "집단주의" (groupism) and "개인주의" (individualism) instead.